# Python iloc slice range from dictionary value

Tags: python, slice

I am trying to use a dictionary value to define the slice ranges for the iloc function but I keep getting the error  --  Can only index by location with a [integer, integer slice (START point is INCLUDED, END point is EXCLUDED), listlike of integers, boolean array] .  The excel sheet is built for visual information and not in any kind of real table format (not mine so I can’t change it) so I have to slice the specific ranges without column labels.

tried code - got the error

```
cr_dict= {'AA':'[42:43,32:65]', 'BB':'[33:34, 32:65]'}

df = my_df.iloc[cr_dict['AA']]
```

the results I want would be similar to

```
df = my_df.iloc[42:43,32:65]
```

I know I could change the dictionary and use the following but it looks convoluted and not as easy to read– is there a better way?

Code

```
cr_dict= {'AA':[42,43,32,65], 'BB':'[33,34, 32,65]'}
df = my_df.iloc[cr_dict['AA'][0]: cr_dict['AA'][0], cr_dict['AA'][0]: cr_dict['AA'][0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Define your dictionaries slightly differently.

```
cr_dict= {'AA':[42,43]+list(range(32,65)), 
          'BB':[33,34]+list(range(32,65))}
```

Then you can slice your DataFrame like so:

```
>>> my_df.iloc[cr_dict["AA"], cr_dict["BB"]].sort_index()
```

Comment: sorry "AA" and "BB" are not the column labels - those were just the dictionary keys.  I added some code to clarify.   I am trying to do Integer based indexing using iloc and have the integer range come from the dictionary.

Comment: So what are the different keys for?

Comment: they are used to determine which range is needed depending on the users selection.   If they select AA it will pull certain values , if they select BB it will pull different values from the excel sheet.

Comment: Not quite what I looking for.      my_df.iloc[42:43,32:65]  give different results than  my_df.iloc[cr_dict["AA"]].sort_index() in this case.

Comment: What is the shape of `my_df`? Also, to understand you better, are you trying to get rows 42 and 43 and columns 32-65?